# How to add a @IBOutlet of a UITableViewCell object in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to add a `@IBOutlet` of a `UITableViewCell` in `Swift 4`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51AmQ.png because I would like to change the row height programmatically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs3qU.png but for some reason I am unable to do it.

I have tried to add it into the `UIViewController` swift file, but then it returns this error:

> The cell outlet from the ShowIssue to the TableViewCell is invalid.
>   Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

I have also tried to add it into the `UITableViewCell` swift file (I use it for adding outlets of objects that are inside in a cell), but it does not allow me to connect it.

How can I get this working?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t connect IBOutlets or the whole cell to `UIViewController`. But what you can do is connect these outlets to subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

So, first create subclass of `UITableViewCell`

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
}
```

then in storyboard don’t forget to change class of your cell

[image]

Now you can connect your IBOutlets to this subclass

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var someView: UIView!
    ...
}
```

so this solves problem with connecting outlets. Now how you can change row height of all cells:

If you need to change height of cells in your `UITableView`, you can set it in your `UIViewController`. But not as height of single cell, but as height of row in `UITableView`

```
yourTableView.rowHeight = 70
```

or you can use auto-layout and then you don't have to set `rowHeight`

Comment: My problem is that I have the whole code for that view inside the UIViewController. So, then I guess I will have to do something like: let var = YourCell() - var.someView.property = 12 correct?

Comment: In ViewController in `cellForRowAt` TableView data source method you have to downcast your dequeued cell as YourCell. Then you have access to YourCell’s outlets

Comment: Ok I will try that but wait, I see you have edited your reply. Does that mean I cannot set the height of a single cell? If so, what I want is to have cells with different height.

Comment: I have just found a better way to get this working. Using UITableView.automaticDimension inside the viewDidLoad adjusts every cell height to its content. Thank you for the help!

Comment: you're also setting `.rowHeight` as in my example, just instead of `70` you're using dynamic `UITableView.automaticDimension`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the *height* of the `TableViewCell` programatically, then you have a delegate method for that namely

> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
>            heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

Use this to return your *custom height for cell*

You need to override it in your *View Controller* and don't forget to provide delegate like :

> myTableView.delegate = self

Comment: I think this method does not exist in the version of swift I am using, so when I start to type func tableViewHeight I only have available these ones: heightForFooterInSection, heightForHeaderInSection, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection and estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection. Also I tried to copy your code and I added override but it has this error: Method does not override any method from its superclass.

Comment: Have you tried conforming to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol like **MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {  }** ?

Comment: Yes, exactly I have: class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {}

Comment: @AdriánT95 Can you share the screenshot for the same . Like for the class and the corresponding error where it says there exists no method like that

Comment: My bad, I have figured out what was going on. Apparently I already had a heightForRowAt method in the code, sorry about that. Anyway I have just found a better way to get this working. Using UITableView.automaticDimension inside the viewDidLoad adjusts every cell height to its content. Thank you for the help!